# Bootstrap Datetime picker dynamic default date not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to update the default date on each link clicked. But it only updates for the first time. After I click another link it still shows old date. But when I debug the `defaultD` is updating.

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
updateSessionDate: function(datetime){  
    $("#updateUTCDate").modal("show");
    var defaultD = moment(datetime, "MMM Do YYYY, h:mm a").format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
    $('#current_session_date').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: defaultD,
    });
},
```

Click any date it will show only the first one I have click.

[image]

How do I update date and time on each click?

Comment: Use `date` instead of `defaultDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#current_session_date').datetimepicker({
  defaultDate: defaultD,
});
```

This creates the `datetimepicker` with an initial value, so doesn't work if the `datetimepicker` already exists.

You either need to call [date([newDate])](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#date) to update it in place (you'll need to initialise it elsewhere) or [destroy()](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#destroy) it when the modal is closed, allowing you to remake it with a new initial value.

Comment: can you show me a demo for destroy() while bootstrap modal close ?

Comment: Instead of defaulltDate I use date . It fixed the issue.